# GitHub importa demasiados objetos

Tags: github

Cada vez que push [este repositorio](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot) siento que importa demasiados objetos:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 31708, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23964/23964), ...
```

Tiene 31708 elementos cuando creo que escribí al menos una quincena.
Sin embargo, tuve un gusto con todo lo que no era necesario :

Aqui esta el `.gitignore`:

```
# Environment
MyFlaskAppEnv/*
MyFlaskAppEnv/

# Under Construction
run_app.py
run_rasa_server.py

# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]

# Distribution / packaging
bin/
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
```

Es necesario? ¡No es muy práctico!

Comment: @gbianchi Disculpe, olviado de precisar que le codigo esta el `.gitignore`

Comment: Estara puesto en el lugar equivocado el archivo?

Comment: No creo que lo que esté contando sean solo tus archivos, deben ser la cantidad de nodos y demás cosas que usa Git internamente para gestionar las versiones de tus archivos.

Comment: @César Esta un numero mu largo sin embargo, no ?